# Windows XP - 'New' Context Menu Items

Tags: windows-xp, php, windows-registry, context-menu

I am attempting to create new items in this context menu.

[image]

Some file extensions cannot be added. I have tried both the TweakUI method and the [manual registry editing method](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/shellnewadd.htm) but both seem to yield nothing (no item appears in the menu) for particular file types (.php, in this case).

Ultimately I want to be able to select a .PHP file (could be blank, or a template) from the New menu and have it spawned where the context menu is brought up. The Template section of TweakUI could do this, if it were not for the fact that .php files refuse to work.

Any ideas why I am unable to add a .php item to the 'New' menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you must associate the .PHP extension first with a program.

Comment: Previously, assoc.php=php_auto_file. I re-associated it to Notepad++_file, and there was no change. Give or take a few association changes, and it started working - I can now add .php files via the 'New' menu. However, I am unsure at what point this started working - 'assoc .php' now returns '.php=Notepad++_file', for the record. Thanks for your help, Cal.

Comment: @Thomas, it's possible that the explorer shell doesn't immediately pick up file association changes (or rather, that the New/template system doesn't) which might explain why you didn't see the change as soon as you made it. Anyway, good question, starred for later reference.